# Application session is shared between users while accessing from different machines

Tags: spring, hibernate, session

I am building an online Examination project with spring mvc and Hibernate as Frameworks and it is almost done, Now I am getting the problem with session

### xml configuration of the session

```
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:value>com.app.spring.model.Result</beans:value>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                    </beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Inject the transaction manager  -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
```

and queries in dao impl are like this

```
@Override
    public void addObject(Object p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        logger.info("Customer saved successfully, Customer Details=" + p);
    }
```

The Exam users will login to application and he have to attempt 20 questions 
The application is in my local machine and which is connected with in network for testing While the Exam is started with two people I am getting the problem like below

Exam pattern is to attempt 20 questions if two people started exam suppose one attempted 10 questions and other attempted 10 questions then the exam is getting completed I am thinking that the session is divided between the users can any one help me how can I overcome this problem.

Comment: That can only happen if you have a stageful component some where and the mistake is probably in your controller. A web session has nothing to do with a hibernate session.

Comment: Could you post your ER diagram. I would expect (at least) 4 Entities, User, Exam, Question, Answer. A User can take many exams, an Exam har many (20) questions, Each Question has many Answers (one for each user). It is extremely that you understand the oneToMany and ManyToMany relations in the datamodel, and model it correctly in Hibernate(JPA). Once you have the correct datamodel, you need to create the UI that tracks the id of users, exams, and questions.

Comment: I dont have multiple tables, The questions and options are in excel sheet I am reading Excel sheet and displaying the question.